# Facebook comments dynamic generated pages unreachable

Tags: facebook, comments

I use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ in my site, on multiple dynamic generate pages. I implement everything for that, incude meta tags, and config facebook app.

Comments generaly work, but problem is Warning: Site ***************** is unreachable.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout what the [Debugger has to say](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tzvpz.hr%2Ftzvpzinstagramapp%2F%3Fid%3D339876160123232275_23409407) about the URL you are providing.

The main thing you need to look at is the **Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed**. They are -

> **Facebook URLs cannot be crawled.**

It is as simple as that. You can't get the information on that page because it redirects to your application.

What you'll need to do, is provide a URL that is accessible to Facebook's crawlers. The [Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is a great tool to monitor how Facebook sees your URL's.

Comment: Please explain detailed this: provide a URL that is accessible to Facebook's crawlers

Comment: A URL that Facebook's crawlers can see. A public URL, one that anyone can access.